# Is there any way to add a watermark on kali terminal's window on windows subsystem?

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

is there any way to add a watermark on the kali linux screen on windows.
I have been trying to find this online but no luck. waiting for help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not using the "default" terminal.  The default terminal in Windows is the legacy "Windows Console."  This is the same application that is used for CMD, PowerShell, and any text-based console application in Windows.  It's a few decades old at this point ...

> ##### [Initial Implementation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap#initial-implementation)
>
> [1989-1990s] The initial console host system was implemented as an emulation of the DOS environment within the Windows operating system. Its code is entangled and cooperative with the Command Prompt, cmd.exe, that is a representation of that DOS environment. The console host system code shares responsibilities and privileges with the Command Prompt interpreter/shell. It also provides a base level of services for other command-line utilities to perform services in a CMD-like manner.

Other, newer terminals offer what you are looking for.  My recommended solution would be to use the newer Windows Terminal, which is designed to be the replacement for Windows Console.  It is:

- Created and maintained by Microsoft
- Available for installation from the Microsoft Store
- Pre-installed in Windows 11
- Automatically detects WSL distributions and adds Profile entries for each
- Open source ([Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal))
- Under active development
- The "Preview" release (also available in the Store as a separate installation) can be set as the Default Terminal in Windows 11.
- And yes, it supports image backgrounds for your Kali session.

Just a note that it will need to be a graphical watermark.  It can't be a "text" watermark, if that happens to be what you are asking.  You can always just use any graphics program to put the text in an image.

Then, in Windows Terminal, go to *Settings*, then select your Kali profile.  Under *Appearance*, select the *Background Image*.  You can set the scaling and transparency as desired.